# How can i get Keywords used in a Search Engine in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

Hi how i can used keywords entred in search engine then navigated to my website with asp.net webform ?
Please Help Me
Thanks

Comment: How can you what? Details? Code? Question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to detect - where did the user came from?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208841/how-to-detect-where-did-the-user-came-from)

Answer (score 1):

Get the referrer - if it is google the keywords they used are in the url

e.g. in your code

```
string referrer = Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_REFERER");
```

if it has come from google the referrer would be something like
https://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=serverVariables

You can see the &q parameter in there and strip it out.